# What info do/should you include in an apps version info?

Tags: versioning

The standard version info is major.minor.bugfix string and build version, but given the following properties, what, and how would you structure your versin info ?

MAJOR_VERSION
MINOR_VERSION
BUGFIX_VERSION
VC_BRANCH
VC_LAST_COMMIT_SHA_HASH
VC_COMMITS_SINCE_LAST_TAG
VC_TAG
BUILD_DATE
BUILD_TIME

Specifically, what would you display to the end-user, and what would you use internally as a build ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Major.minor.build is all I've ever needed. You can add whatever extra info you want, but frankly I don't see the point.